# Where to learn basics of group homology via algebraic topology?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, group-cohomology

What are good refences for group co/homology, mostly from the perspective of algebraic topology? Suppose I have student who has studied the first three chapters of Hatcher and I want him or her to learn:

- $BG$ classifies principal G-bundles.
- If $E$ is contractible with a free $G$ action and $E \to E/G$ is a fibration, then the homotopy type of $E/G$ only depends on $G$.
- $H^*(BG)$ give characteristic classes for principal $G$-bundles.
- $H_*(BG)=\operatorname{Tor}^{\mathbb Z[G]}(\mathbb Z,\mathbb Z)$.
- $BG$ is the realization of a simplicial set with set of $p$-simplices given by $G^p$.

Notes or textbook suggestsions are welcome.

Comment: Try Brown, *Cohomology of groups*.

Comment: Spelling note:  'principal', not 'principle', bundle.  MathJax note:  you need a space after the bullet for MathJax to format it as a bulleted list.  I have edited accordingly on both counts.

Comment: This is going to sound somewhat ridiculous, but I feel that all of these could be written up as a nice exercise sheet for your student to work through themselves (with a handful of guiding hints for each).

Comment: Try Benson, "Representations and cohomology", volume 2